# Nuxt 3 app on IIS not serving static files

Tags: iis, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to deploy a Nuxt 3 app on a server using IIS.
The idea is to use reverse proxy to rewrite requests from the external `https://www.example.com` to the internal `http://localhost:8080` where the app is running.

It should be straight forward I thought, with an inbound rule matching everything `(.*)` and a Rewrite URL like `http://localhost:8080/{R:1}`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But apparently only the dynamic routes are being served correctly, all public static files are not. On those this is the curl response: `curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)`.

Other notes:

- Opening the app locally on `http://localhost:8080` works perfectly.
- The same behaviour occurs with a fresh Nuxt app.
- Usage of `iisnode` seems not possible because of ES Modules incompatibility: `iisnode Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module (...)index.mjs not supported.`

Comment: Do you have ARR installed? Post your `web.config`'s `<rewrite>` section, not a screenshot of IIS. Do you have any IIS virtual-directories or application-scopes set-up in the same IIS Website?

Comment: Yes ARR is installed. Ok will edit the answer. There are other sites on that IIS, but not virtual-directories ot application-scopes I believe.

Answer (score 0):

After adding a rule to force HTTPS it started working as expected, all static files are being served as expected.

```xml
<rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```